# How to delete last n rows in a file by using bash file?

Tags: sed

I want to delete some specific rows in a file. For example I have a file containing these rows:

```
+1  1:-51.000000
+1  1:-47.000000
+1  1:-53.000000
+1  1:-48.000000
+1  1:-49.000000
+1  1:-42.000000
```

I want to delete the last 3 rows. How to do that in bash file?

Comment: Thank you...i'm sorry the row here is the same with line. but your syntax does not work, it said "sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command"

Comment: That syntax is a GNU `sed` extension.

Comment: @mbratch: address arithmetic is usually not supported by sed, which version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nl=`wc -l fileName | awk 's=$1-3{print s}'`; head -n $nl fileName > file_withoutlast3rows.txt
```

`wc -l` calculates the total number of lines in the file. Using awk, you can print the total number of lines `-3`. Then use `head` with `-n` option to read only that many lines. You can also put that many lines into a new file using `>`.

You can also use `awk` to do this :

```
awk -v nl=$(wc -l <fileName) 'NR<(nl-2)' fileName
```

Comment: It would be more efficient if you kept an array of three lines, and printed the current cell's previous content (if any) before replacing it. Hint: `NR%3`

Answer (score 0):

Simply count the number of lines, calculate the first index, and use `sed -i` to delete it.

```
COUNT=$(wc -l < file)
INDEX=$((COUNT > 3 ? COUNT - 2 : 1))
sed -i "$INDEX,\$d" file
```

Or just use bash's readarray:

```
readarray LINES < file
LAST=$((${#LINES[@]} > 3 ? ${#LINES[@]} - 3 : 0))
printf "%s" "${LINES[@]:0:LAST}" > file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '1N;$!N;$d;P;D' file
```

for say 5 lines:

```
 sed ':a;$!N;s/.*/&/m5;Ta;$d;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only `awk` with no external commands like `wc`.
Read the file twice

```
awk 'NR==FNR {i++;next} (i-FNR)>=3' file file
```